# Pad an array with incrementing numbers

Tags: php

Is it possible to pad an array with incrementing numbers? For example

```
$myArr = ["red", "green", "blue"];
$type = "colour";
```

I want to somehow merge these and add a sort order so I end up with the following

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [type] => "colour"
            [sort] => 1
        )
    [green] => Array
        (
            [type] => "colour"
            [sort] => 2
        )
    [blue] => Array
        (
            [type] => "colour"
            [sort] => 3
        )
)
```

So far I have only managed:

```
$additional_data = array_pad([], count($myArr), ['type_id' => $type_id]);
$data = array_combine($myArr, $additional_data);
```

which is yielding:

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [type] => "colour"
        )
    [green] => Array
        (
            [type] => "colour"
        )
    [blue] => Array
        (
            [type] => "colour"
        )
)
```

I know I can do it by iterating through colours, but wondered if it could be done without a loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version which you posted to solve this problem always has 1 as the sort_order.

```
$myArr = ["red", "green", "blue"];
$type_id = "colour";
$sort = 0;

$additional_data = array_pad([], count($myArr), ['type_id' => $type_id, 'sort_order' => ++$sort]);
$data = array_combine($myArr, $additional_data);
print_r($data);
```

outputs...

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => colour
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [green] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => colour
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [blue] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => colour
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

)
```

You could then process the result with array_walk to correct the values...

```
$myArr = ["red", "green", "blue"];
$type_id = "colour";
$sort = 0;

$additional_data = array_pad([], count($myArr), ['type_id' => $type_id, 'sort_order' => ++$sort]);
$data = array_combine($myArr, $additional_data);
$sort = 1;
array_walk($data, function (&$item, $key) use(&$sort) {
    $item['sort_order'] = $sort++;
});

print_r($data);
```

Which corrects it to.

```
Array
(
    [red] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => colour
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [green] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => colour
            [sort_order] => 2
        )

    [blue] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => colour
            [sort_order] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes of course you are right. I didn't spot that.  This works, although I am not sure it is any less ugly than a loop.  At least I know now though. Thanks

Comment: It's a matter of choice, loops are good at some things, the `array_*` methods suite others.  But main thing is to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I done this, hope can help

```
$myArr = ["red", "green", "blue"];
$type = "colour";

$x = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($myArr);$i++){
$x[$myArr[$i]]=array();
$x[$myArr[$i]]["type"]=$type;
$x[$myArr[$i]]["sort"]=$i;
}
var_dump($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Pretty simple really.

```
$myArr = ["red", "green", "blue"];
$type = "colour";
$sort = 0;

$additional_data = array_pad([], count($myArr), ['type_id' => $type_id, 'sort_order' => ++$sort]);
$data = array_combine($myArr, $additional_data);
```